# Need an efficient and faster script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
**function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}
function addTimestamp(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if(col === 10 && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Phy-JEE-Eng- 208_206_53")
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,11).getValue()== ""){
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,11).setValue(new Date());
  }
}**
```

the above script is used in getting timestamp in a column (B) adjacent to column (A), When ever someone adds any value / clicks the checkbox in column (A). but the problem arises when someone selects a bunch or rows and tries to tick the checkbox by hitting space button, and when someone wants to paste bulk values into multiple rows in column (A), the script is only working in the cell which is the primary point (highlighted cell) of selection in an array of selection. I need a function where whenever something is added in any cell I should get a timestamp, looking for some suggestions other than OnEdit!

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && sh.getName() == "Phy-JEE-Eng- 208_206_53") {
    if (e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue() == "") {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```